# How do I remove the DocuSign watermark from a signed PDF?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have implemented DocuSign in my application for signing the PDF but after making signature some details regarding DocuSign information is displaying in PDF in red color. Please find the Image. Can anyone suggest me how to hide this information from the PDF after making signature?

[image: Image of PDF with red watermark]

Comment: We know Bimal's birthday now, let's send him presents :D!

Comment: Flagged this for removal.  OMG, don't include personal information like this on the internet!  What is wrong with you?

Comment: Please please please please please tell me that SSN is completely fake...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it includes personal information that should be removed.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Closing won't help as the question will still be around. Flagging is better. Two fold issue: OP appears to have dropped off, and SSN is [potentially valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number#Valid_SSNs), although based on the other data on the form probably not deliberately.

Comment: I flagged, but the moderators told me they wouldn't remove.  Just trying to get rid of this.  Actually, The recent edit of the image is a nice solution.

Answer (score 4):

The watermark in the upper right corner cannot be removed and will be applied to all documents signed in DocuSign's Demo environment. If you would like to have documents signed without that watermark you will need to go live and being making calls in the Production environment.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate upon Drew's answer:

- You're seeing the red watermark on the documents because the Envelope was sent using DocuSign's "demo" environment, which is free and intended for use only as a development/testing environment. (They add the watermark to documents in the "demo" environment to discourage folks from using the "demo" environment for production scenarios without paying for the DocuSign service.)
- If you want to send Envelopes and ***not*** have the red watermark appear on the documents, you'll need to pay for a DocuSign subscription, and then send your Envelopes using DocuSign's "production" environment.

Also worth noting: if you're using the DocuSign API to send and/or manage Envelopes, you'll need to complete the "API Certification" process to get your Integrator Key approved for use in the production environment, before your API calls will work against production endpoints. For information about that process, see the **Go Live with Your DocuSign Integration** section here: https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#go-live.